# Python3 Renaming Files By tkinter Listbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I want to rename all files in a directory by tkinter listbox.

Got stuck at this point:

```
files_list = os.listdir(root.foldername)
print(files_list)
```

gives me

```
['1.mp4', '10.mp4', '2.mp4', '3.mp4', '4.mp4', '5.mp4', '6.mp4', '7.mp4', '8.mp4', '9.mp4']

values = [listbox.get(idx) for idx in listbox.curselection()]<br>
```

And

```
inlist = (', '.join(values))<br>
print(inlist)
```

gives me

```
Lost - 1x01 - Pilot(1), Lost - 1x02 - Pilot(2), Lost - 1x03 - Tabula Rasa, Lost - 1x04 - Walkabout, Lost - 1x05 - White Rabbit, Lost - 1x06 - House Of The Rising Sun, Lost - 1x07 - The Moth, Lost - 1x08 - Confidence Man, Lost - 1x09 - Solitary, Lost - 1x10 - Raised By Another
```

Now I'm looking for a solution to use os.rename in order to rename the files 1.mp4 till 10.mp4.
Additionally Python for whatever reason does not come with a built-in way to have natural sorting, so it sorts 1.mp4 followed by 10.mp4.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For natural sorting take a look at [Sorting alphanumeric strings in Python](https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/sorting-alphanumeric-strings-in-python/).

Then loop through all files and rename them, eg.

```
for i in range(len(files_list)):
    old_file_name = files_list[i]
    new_file_name = values[i] + '.mp4'
    os.rename(old_file_name, new_file_name)
```

For assistance in dealing with pathnames see `os.path`.